# Space bar and arrow keys on Radio buttons trigger TypeError: Error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I've just discovered a bug in my app, it looks like a Flash player bug, i would like to know if anyone has found a workaround or something.

I've some radio buttons groups in my app. If I press the arrow keys while holding the spacebar pressed, it ends up triggering

```
  TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at fl.controls::LabelButton/drawIcon()
    at fl.controls::LabelButton/draw()
    at fl.controls::RadioButton/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
```

If found [this thread](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?819852-wacky-bug-in-flash-component) that describes my same situation. 
Do you think there's any workaround for this? Is it really a flash bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I've investigated this problem and found, that there is an error in standard fl components. It is not only about RadioButton. If you hold SpaceBar and then switch current UI element by clicking "TAB" button - you will receive similar error.

To solve it, you should fix source of the component: in class `LabelButton`, method `keyUpHandler` replace code

```
setMouseState(oldMouseState);
```

with

```
if (oldMouseState!==null) {
    setMouseState(oldMouseState);
}
```

and add override:

```
override protected function focusOutHandler(event:FocusEvent):void {
    if (oldMouseState) {
        keyUpHandler(new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, true, true, 0, Keyboard.SPACE));
    }

    super.focusOutHandler(event);
}
```

If you don't know, how you can do it:

1. just copy `Adobe Flash CS5 install folder\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface\fl\controls\LabelButton.as` to another directory with the same package structure `\fl\controls\LabelButton.as`
2. then you need include this duplicated structure to project.

It is not very good way, but in this case it really fixes this error. BTW, I'll send it to Adobe.

Comment: I've implemented your solution, thx :) I'm just waiting for the community to evaluate other solutions, but the bounty will probably be yours

Comment: Glad to hear, that answer was useful. The main problem is that fl components are separated from the mx components and they are not the part of flex sdk. And I don't understand why it so - community can fix errors like these by itself and very fast.

Answer (score 1):

actually its not a flash bug its component's bug. if space bar is no need for your radio buttons(i think its useless) you can disable it with creating your own MyRadioButton which extends RadioButton class this will be disable space key input

```
package  {
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import fl.controls.RadioButton;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

public class MyRadioButton extends RadioButton{

    public function MyRadioButton() {
        super();
    }

    override protected function keyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if(event.keyCode != Keyboard.SPACE){
            super.keyUpHandler(event);
        }
    }

    override protected function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if(event.keyCode != Keyboard.SPACE){
            super.keyDownHandler(event);
        }
    }

}
```

}

just you need to change class property fl.controls.RadioButton to MyRadioButton from your library element:"RadioButton". (i assume MyRadioButton is near fla)

------>edit

here is another solution without disabling spacebar. this time when user makes anykeydown before spacebar keyup code runs spacebar keyup before anykeydown. and focus get removed from radio button also you can add anyother solutions like if spacebar keystate is down donot let any keydown.

```
package  {
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import fl.controls.RadioButton;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;

public class MyRadioButton extends RadioButton{

private var _isSpaceDown:Boolean = false;

    public function MyRadioButton() {
        super();
    }

    override protected function handleChange(event:Event):void {
        if (_isSpaceDown) {
            keyUpHandler(new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, true, true, 0, Keyboard.SPACE));
            setMouseState('up');
        }
        super.handleChange(event);
    }


    override protected function keyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
            if(_isSpaceDown){
                _isSpaceDown = false;
            }else{
                return;  
            }
        }           
        super.keyUpHandler(event);
    }

    override protected function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
            _isSpaceDown = true;                
        }else{
            if(_isSpaceDown){                   
                var e:KeyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN);
                e.keyCode = Keyboard.SPACE;
                super.keyUpHandler(e);
                _isSpaceDown = false;
            }
        }           
        super.keyDownHandler(event);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, but it is not good solution - keybord may be very helpful in UI and we must avoid cutting off this functionality.

Comment: sure but i think spacebar is useless(not the keyboard :) ) i couldnt use it as user on RadioButton. i checked your solution but i dont think problem is oldmousestate that fix just fixes the error not fixes the usability. if you want to use space bar im adding another solution

Comment: I've added solution with full fix at now. Checked with buttons and radiobutton mix. Yes, problem is deep enough, but it could be fixed, just need to test. And again - it is not problem only for RadioButton. Btw, if you find bugs in my solution - please, tell me. Thanks.

Comment: i tested. it has little bug with focusout for usability not a big deal but i suggest to use override handleChange not focusout i overrided mine too becuse it was going buggy when clicking radiobuttons with spacebar

Comment: Thanks for response. I don't like this override focusOut too, but handleChange - is RadioButton's method, so it will be not enough to fix Button and so on.